# How to check Daemon Thread status in java?

Tags: java

In myprogram I need to check if daemon thread is finished or not.
Can I use `isAlive()` method for Daemon thread?

Comment: I guess `yes`, you can use it on any thread, though I would leave it to experts = !

Comment: I am not sure.May be i should give broader scenario in which i am working.I is related to struts 1.3 Action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), the `isAlive()` method doesn't care if your thread is a daemon or not, a daemon is still a thread so to answer your question, yes you can.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can ask the Thread for its current status by calling:

```
Thread.State ts = thread.getState();
```

and you should get one of the follwing:

A thread state. A thread can be in one of the following states:

- **NEW**
  A thread that has not yet started is in this state.
- **RUNNABLE**
  A thread executing in the Java virtual machine is in this state.
- **BLOCKED**
  A thread that is blocked waiting for a monitor lock is in this state.
- **WAITING**
  A thread that is waiting indefinitely for another thread to perform a particular action is in this state.
- **TIMED_WAITING**
  A thread that is waiting for another thread to perform an action for up to a specified waiting time is in this state.
- **TERMINATED**
  A thread that has exited is in this state.